# How to convert RichTextBox.Selection.Start to int?

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox

How to convert RichTextBox.Selection.Start to int?

In winforms, you can do this :

`int i = richTextBox.SelectionStart;`

How to do the same in WPF?

All I need is the int value of the start position of the selection.

I tried to find information on this issue, but all was in vain. There are quite a few methods in RichTextBox.Selection.Start in wpf, but none seem to give the desired result. It is very strange that so many difficulties arose with such a simple task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not entirely clear from your question what you want to achieve.

The `RichTextBox` in the WinForms and WPF have totally different approach to manipulate with the flow document content.

But to get text offset from the beginning of document  to the current selection you can try the following:

```cs
var tr = new TextRange(richTextBox.Selection.Start, richTextBox.Document.ContentStart);
var index = tr.Text.Length;
```

Take to account, that lines in WinForms `RichTextBox` are ended with `\n` and in the WPF with `\r\n`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your solution is exactly what I need. This is a learning task to create a primitive text editor. A month earlier, there was a similar task on winforms and there were no problems with it. In the WPF, everything turned out to be a little more complicated. I realized that the WPF uses a different approach. But I'm not sure I need to study it yet. It is unlikely that I will ever write text editors in vpf. Is there a similar approach used elsewhere in C#?

Comment: @ПавелСпасский: It's not related to the _C#_ language. What I am talking about is the `FlowDocument` structure and the context related methods used to work with the document. Details you can find here: [FlowDocument Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.flowdocument?view=netframework-4.8.1).

Answer (score 1):

Get both the start of the selection and the start of the document as a `TextPointer`. You can then use the [`GetOffsetToPosition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.documents.textpointer.getoffsettoposition) method to calculate the distance between the two in text symbols.

```
TextPointer selStart = richTextBox.Selection.Start;
TextPointer docStart = richTextBox.Document.ContentStart;
int offset = docStart.GetOffsetToPosition(selStart);
```